# Problem due fileupload via $_POST

Tags: php, flash, post

im try to catch a fileupload from my Flashfile, this sends it with $_POST to my File upload.php.

Maybe anyone find my Bug, the File was'nt uploaded.

```
$data = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
$fp = fopen("upload/".$session."/".$wkid."/".$data, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

The Header of POST looks like:

```
http://192.168.1.161:81/upload.php

POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.161:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=9873ceb6399eafefb91dac3b942d0b78; __utma=48168551.1670897330.1298964838.1298964838.1298968544.2; __utmc=48168551; __utmz=48168551.1298964838.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); phpMyAdmin=f54c4ad7eb21706a57b4b6e5058dd2cfbea1cc32; pma_lang=de-utf-8; pma_charset=utf-8; pma_mcrypt_iv=UX8VuU94d%2BA%3D; pmaUser-1=SNAWkCqwJCg%3D; pmaPass-1=eV3KOmsoVPlmV1Z%2BYkskZQ%3D%3D; pma_fontsize=82%25; pma_theme=original; __utmb=48168551.2.10.1298968544; session=9873ceb6399eafefb91dac3b942d0b78; wkid=314; uid=25c75688b1e929d494fea85a0d6a8439
Referer: http://192.168.1.161:81/upload.swf
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-length: 73371

PNG


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 08:35:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 35
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue might be this part:

```
$fp = fopen("upload/".$session."/".$wkid."/".$data, "wb");
```

`$data` was set to the raw POST payload. And with this fopen call you are trying to create a filename with the raw bytestream (possibly over 10K) in its name. While this depends on the actual filesystem, it is most likely to fail on most BSD/Linux servers.

Comment: hi mario, i tried befor with $_FILES['name']['tmp_name'] but the file cannot moved out of /tmp and got always deleted after processing.

Comment: @raz: That's not the problem here. Use something like `$destfilename = md5($data)` and that in fopen() rather than $data.

Comment: Also you probably wanted to use `$_FILES["data"]["name"]` and not `tmp_name`

Comment: @mario i tried this: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "upload/".$session."/".$wkid."/".$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']), but its dont worked.

Comment: @raz: Again, You cannot use `tmp_name` for the destination filename.

Comment: @mario, oh sorry, copied the wrong line, edited to: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "upload/".$session."/".$wkid."/".$_FILES['file']['name']); and the same result.

Comment: @raz: That's correct. But with your above example (raw POST data), the `$_FILES` array is not going to work anyway.

Comment: @mario, solved the problem had a ´logical error in my Brain´ ;-) i dont use yet move_uploaded_files... Now i use the fgets("php://input"); and define a filename... wring filename was my error due i tried to write the file contents to the filename. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try reading the raw post data with:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Hi Smott, this works good! But the created file have a wrong name, (eg: ?PNG????) a idea how to get the correct name? thanks in advance